# When does BlockingObservable.last() return?

Tags: java, rx-java

When does `BlockingObservable.last()` return ? Does it wait until the underlying `Observable` calls `onComplete` or does it just return the last item emitted so far, while the `Observable` might emit more items in the future ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the diagrams in [the javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/BlockingObservable.html), first see the legend of the marble diagrams for `BlockingObservable` :

[image: BlockingObservable legend]

Then the marble diagram for `last()` :

[image: BlockingObservable.last()]

This diagram tells us that `last()` will return once the `Observable` has completed, i.e. once `onComplete` *or `onError`* have been called (that last part is not clear from the docs). It will throw `NoSuchElementException` if either `onComplete` or `onError` are called before any items are emitted. If you don't want it to throw exceptions, use `lastOrDefault()`.